# Is this a partial ordering or an equivalence relation?

Tags: functions, relations, order-theory

I think it's a partial ordering and therefore not an equivalence relation. Is this right?

> Let $X$ be the set of functions from finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ to $\ulcorner 2\urcorner$={0,1} (that is $f\in X$ iff there is a finite set $D\subseteq\Bbb N$ such that $f:D\to\ulcorner 2\urcorner$). Define a relation $R$ on $X$ as follows: if $f,g\in X$, $f\mathrel{R}g$ iff $\operatorname{Dom}(g)\subseteq\operatorname{Dom}(f)$ and $g=f|_{\operatorname{Dom}(g)}$. Is $R$ a partial ordering? Is $R$ an equivalence relation?

Comment: And what in the world is that funny thing [2] written there, anyway? I think it is better you type the question here.

Comment: The funny [2] = {0,1} weird notation sorry hahah

Comment: Stack exchange doesn't allow me to type the question

Comment: Your idea seems almost right. You are just missing the fact that there actually *is* a relation which is both a partial ordering and an equivalence: the identity (and the identity alone).

Comment: You mean *equivalence **relation***, not *equivalence **class***.

Comment: You should learn how to type this question in using MathJax.  There is help on that if when you edit your question you click the help.

Comment: There’s a MathJax tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It is a partial ordering, but as **G. Sassatelli** pointed out, that alone does not guarantee that it’s not an equivalence relation. The easiest way to show that it’s not an equivalence relation is to show by example that it’s not symmetric. To show that it’s a partial order, you need to prove that it’s reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive. It’s not hard, but you do need to supply the proofs.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $R$ is a (non-empty, not complete) partial ordering we must establish three points:

- If $fRg$ and $gRh$ then $fRh$.

Proof: $fRg \implies f \supseteq g \wedge \forall s\in \mbox{ dom }(g): f(s) = g(s)$.  In that case, $ f \supseteq g \wedge g \supseteq h \implies f \supseteq h $ and in the domain of $h$, $g(s) = h(s)$ and $f(x) = g(s)$ so $f(s) = h(s)$.

- There exist some $\{f,g\}$ such that $fRg$.

Proof:  Consider as an example $f(n)$ defined on $(1,2,3,4$ such that $f(n) = \frac{1}{n+1}$ and $g(n)$ defined on $(1,2)$ such that $g(n) = \frac{1}{n+1}$. It is easy to check that $fRg$.

- There exists some  $\{f,g\}$ such that neither $fRg$ nor $gRf$.

Proof: Consider any two functions defined on domains which are not ordered by subset inclusion; for example, the domain of $f$ is $(1,2,3)$ and the domain of $g$ is $(2,3,4)$.  Then by the subset criterion, neither $fRg$ nor $gRf$.

Now to show this is not an equivalence relationship, we need only find $\{f,g\}$ such that $fRg$ but not $gRf$, for that would violate the reflexivity property. A good example is the example used in the second step of hte partial ordering proof.

Comment: Apparently you proved that $R$ is a non-empty, non-total transitive relation. How does it follow that it is reflexive and anti-symmetric? The first point proves transitivity. The second proves non-emptyness, but not reflexivity, which is necessary, and reflexivity entails non-emptyness. The third point proves it is not a total order, but is not necessary since a partial order can be a total order, and then there is still the anti-symmetry to prove...